# Fazer um update aos dados associados a um nome especifico numa Base de Dados por PHP e SQL

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

**UPDATE:**
Esta questão vai ser longa - de notar que eu sou **muito inexperiente em PHP**.
Eu tenho estado a (tentar) criar uma pagina web que possa aceder a uma base de dados criada em PHPMyAdmin nos ultimos dias, esta neste momento consegue inserir dados na base de dados sem problema.

No entanto encontrei bastantes problemas na parte de fazer update aos dados. Eu vou apresentar tudo o que tenho até agora e no final deixar imagens de como gostava que o codigo procedesse.

**atualizar.php** - Em primeiro lugar o codigo da pagina principal, [este apenas tem uma caixa de texto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxGxS.png) com um script associado para autocomplete (de modo a facilitar a escolha do nome a pesquisar). O objetivo deste script é enviar o nome para o proximo script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
            <script> 
                jQuery(function(){ 
                $("#search").autocomplete("search.php");
                });
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="get" action="get_form.php">
        Nome a pesquisar: <input type="text" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Escreva um nome">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

A partir daqui é que começam as minhas dificuldades, estes 2 ultimos scripts seguintes.

**get_form.php** - O objetivo neste é criar uma tabela com os dados pesquisados para posteriormente permitir a edição dos mesmos. [A tabela é assim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJG9S.png).

```
    <?php

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "rhumanos";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

    //problem variable
    $nome = $_GET['q'];
    // echo $nome;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM trabalhador WHERE nome like '%".$nome."%' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1 align="center">Detalhes</h1>
    <table border="1" align="center" style="line-height:25px;">

        <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Horario</th>
        <th>Salario</th>
        <th>Cargo</th>
        <th>Telefone</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Setor</th>
        <th>Localidade</th>
        </tr>

    <?php
    //Fetch Data form database
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['horario']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['salario']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cargo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['telefone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['e_mail']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['setor']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['localidade']; ?></td>
            <!--Edit option -->
            <td><a href="edit.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>" alt="edit">Editar</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Nome nao encontrado</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**edit.php** - O ultimo script [cria uma tabela para posterior ediçao](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6ve4.png) e os dados sao, ***[supostamente atualizados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNMnm.png)*** mas no final eu explico o meu problema

```
<?php
//Database Connection
// include 'conn.php';
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "rhumanos";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//Get ID from Database
 if($_GET['edit_id']){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM trabalhador WHERE nome= '".$_GET['edit_id']."'" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}

//Update Information

if(isset($_POST['btn-update'])){

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $localidade = $_POST['localidade'];
    $setor = $_POST['setor'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $salario = $_POST['salario'];
    $horario = $_POST['horario'];

    $update = "UPDATE trabalhador SET nome='$nome', cargo='$cargo', e_mail='$email', localidade='$localidade', setor='$setor', email='$email', telefone='$telefone', salario='$salario', horario='$horario' 
    WHERE nome=". $_GET['edit_id'];

    $up = mysqli_query($conn, $update);
    if(!isset($sql)) {
        die ("Erro $sql" .mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else {  
        header("location: get_form.php");
    }
}
?>
<!--Create Edit form -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
    <h1>Editar Informação</h1>
        <label>Nome:</label><input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" value="<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>"><br/><br/>
        <label>Cargo:</label><input type="text" name="cargo" placeholder="Cargo" value="<?php echo $row['cargo']; ?>"><br/><br/>
        <label>E-mail:</label><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" value="<?php echo $row['e_mail']; ?>"><br/><br/>
        <label>Localidade:</label><input type="text" name="localidade" placeholder="Localidade" value="<?php echo $row['localidade']; ?>"><br/><br/>
        <label>Setor:</label><input type="text" name="setor" placeholder="Setor" value="<?php echo $row['setor']; ?>"><br/><br/>
        <label>Telefone:</label><input type="text" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" value="<?php echo $row['telefone']; ?>"><br/><br/>
        <label>Salário:</label><input type="text" name="salario" placeholder="Salário" value="<?php echo $row['salario']; ?>"><br/><br/>    
        <label>Horário:</label><input type="text" name="horario" placeholder="Horário" value="<?php echo $row['horario']; ?>"><br/><br/>            
        <button type="submit" name="btn-update" id="btn-update" onClick="update()"><strong>Update</strong></button>
    <a href="get_form.php"><button type="button" value="button">Cancel</button></a>
</form>

    <!-- Alert for Updating -->
    <script>
    function update(){
        var x;
        if(confirm("Atualizado") == true){
            x= "update";
        }
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

No final [eu recebo este erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRDMG.png).

A variável **q** nao está a ser definida no final onde eu confirmo a mudança (update) dos dados pelo que eu percebo, embora tenha sido definida no inicio, o que me deixa confuso pois nao sei como solucionar.

**Este erro em si mostra todos os dados, de todos os utilizadores na base de dados e eu apenas quero que me mostre o que sofreu mudanças**.

Mais uma vez agradeço qualquer ajuda que seja disponibilizada... esta vai ser das grandes se for arranjada.

PS: Eu sei que o codigo está a deixar o sistema vulnerável devido a potenciais SQL Injections mas como sou o unico a fazer este projeto e a mexer na base de dados por apenas ser acedida por PHPMyAdmin eu não estou a priorizar já a segurança. Estou ciente do perigo no entanto pois já fui informado numa outra pergunta que eu postei.

Comment: O problema é que ele não está entrando neste if > `if(isset($_GET['q']))` então a variável `$row` não foi definida. E isso acontece porque não tem existe o `$_GET['q']`

Comment: A variável q nao está a ser definida ocorre porque ao executar `header("location: get_form.php");` na pagina `edit.php` na `url` não está sendo enviado o parâmetro `q`

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você esqueceu de definir o método GET no seu formulário. O mesmo deve ficar dessa maneira.

```
<form method="get" action="get_form.php">
```

Caso ainda não funcione, tente verificar esta linha adicionando um else. Acontece que GET['q'] não chega e a variável $row acaba não sendo definida,

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
```

Comment: Alterei o form como sugeriu mas nao deu resultado, o erro aparece na mesma. No entanto sim, o erro está nessa variável que nao está a obter a informaçao pretendida. Eu coloquei uma pequena condiçao `else { echo 'erro isset';` para confirmar.

Comment: a questao foi atualizada

Comment: Você visualiza a variável $_GET['q'] no navegador?

Answer (score 0):

- A variável q nao está a ser definida

  > ocorre porque ao executar `header("location: get_form.php");` na pagina `edit.php` na `url` não está sendo enviado o parâmetro `q`
- e eu apenas quero que me mostre o que sofreu mudanças

**Para solucionar os dois problemas:**

coloque dois parâmetros na url do header location

```
header("location: get_form.php?up=ok&q=".$_GET['edit_id']);
```

o parâmetro `up` indica que foi feito UPDATE e o valor do parâmetro `q` é do que sofreu atualização.

A página `get_form.php`

```
//problem variable
$nome = $_GET['q'];
//echo $nome;

if (isset($_GET['up'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM trabalhador WHERE nome = '$nome'";
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM trabalhador WHERE nome like '%".$nome."%' ";
}
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

OBS: essa sintaxe

> `$update = "UPDATE trabalhador SET ......... 
>     WHERE nome=".$_GET['edit_id'];`

parece não funcionar

**Sugiro essa sintaxe**

> `$get = $_GET['edit_id'];
>   $update = "UPDATE trabalhador SET ......... 
>   WHERE nome='$get'";`